# sql statement with min and max

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to write a statement using min and max together.

```
SELECT companyname  FROM companies JOIN stocklist 
USING (companyid) where price =some(
( select max(price) from stocklist) , ( select min(price) from stocklist) ) ;
```

I need to get the companies name for the most low and max value but this isn't working (because of the last line) what is wrong and how should I do that?

UPDATE:

```
select companyname from stockList join companies using (companyid) WHERE price IN (select min(price) from stocklist) ;
```

this is working for me but gets only one operand, how can I get two?

Comment: Where price = max(price) or price = min(price)

Comment: You have the `USING` reserved word in your queries. `USING` isn't part of MySQL.  Are you sure your question is correctly tagged MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

I don't like the idea of having two subqueries in an IN clause.  Here is another way with the join being made explicit:

```
SELECT companyname 
FROM companies c JOIN
     stocklist s
     c.companyid = s.companyid join
     (select min(price) as minprice, max(price) as maxprice
      from stocklist
     ) sm
     on s.price = minprice or s.price = maxprice
```

Comment: Agree, extracting two aggregated values from the same table in separate subqueries to use them in an `IN` clause seems a bit overkill. But it should be perfectly fine to use IN for `minprice` and `maxprice`, i.e. `s.price IN (minprice, maxprice)` – hardly more efficient than using `OR`, but definitely more concise and thus perhaps a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT companyname  FROM companies c
INNER JOIN stocklist s
ON c.companyid = s.companyid
WHERE price IN
((SELECT MAX(price) FROM stocklist ), 
 (SELECT MIN(price) FROM stocklist ))
```

[SEE THIS FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eb6dd/4)

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'companies c
INNER JOIN stocklist s
ON c.companyid = s.companyid
WHERE price IN
(' at line 1

Comment: @Nusha I would call your comment a **BS** (no mincing of words there ;-) ) Check his sqlfiddle's answer, it has no syntax error: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eb6dd/4

Comment: @Nusha I can't see no error on this query. Try to change the fieldnames or tablenames that matches with your tablename.

Comment: no its not working.. anyway I tries this query that work.. but I can't add another operand to the subquery ... what can I do?
SELECT companyname FROM stockList JOIN companies USING (companyid)
WHERE price IN (SELECT min(price) FROM stocklist) ;